# C# oracle : catch all exceptions relative to connectivity?

Tags: c#, oracle, exception

In c#, can I catch all errors about (non) connectivity to an Oracle database?

I don't want to catch error about badly written query but only errors like No listener, connection lost...

If queries are badly written (or table are missing) then this is my fault. 
But if Oracle or the network is down then this should be held by another department.

Answer (score 2):

Write your code in which you build the connection in a try catch part:

```
try
{
   BuildConnection(connectionString);
}
catch (OracleException ex)
{
   //Connectivity Error
}
```

Comment: I don't build the connection myself but I delegate it to an object that could fail (and that will return the underlying error)

Answer (score 2):

Errors between ORA-12150 to ORA-12236 are related to connection errors. A few examples:

> ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
>
> ORA-12152: TNS:unable to send break message
>
> ORA-12157: TNS:internal network communication error

Please refer to https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17766/net12150.htm

Comment: Probably the best answer for now. There are range of errors but guessing the purpose of each range is left to the user (12150->12236 is TNS related). So it's not really usefull. Connection lost (ora-03135) is in the same range that "exceeded procedure space usage" or "invalid tablespace name"

Comment: Becareful, ORA-12545 is a connectivity issue and it is not in the proposed range!

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer for this Type of problem is Use `Try Catch` Block like

```
try
{
   // your code
}
catch (OracleException ex)
{

}
```

[MSDN HELP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleexception%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: I don't want to catch all Oracle exception only those related to unavailability of the database

Answer (score 0):

Sure - you can catch specific exception types, or if they're all the same exception type, you can catch it, check to see if it's a specific type, and re-throw ones you don't want to handle. Not having your syntax, here's an example...

```
try
{
   // your Oracle code
}
catch (OracleException ex)
{
   if (ex.Message == "Something you don't want caught")
   {
      throw;
   }
   else
   {
       // handle
   }
}
```

Comment: That will get messy quickly. Even looking for say the error number is very fragile. Better to wrap each "line" of oracle code in a try catch.

Answer (score 0):

errors like No listener, connection lost are still caught in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException, however, you may inspect ErrorCode and Errors to handle different situations accordingly, say, not listener or connection lost etc.

MSDN does not seem to document all possible errors, however, you may write a few unit tests or integration tests to learn what appear in ErrorCode and Errors, then write error handlers in production codes accordingly.

OracleException contains only ErrorCode not Errors. So you may be using switch(e.ErrorCode) to handle different situations.

Comment: It is not reliable to examine error message, since the message might be changed over next release/fix of .NET framework. Always use ErrorCode.

Answer (score 0):

I observed that each time a network exception occurs, then a SocketException can be found in inner exceptions.

I also observed that when a network exception occurs, the first inner exception is of type «OracleInternal.Network.NetworkException» but unfortunately, this class is internal...

Based on this observations, I would code something like this:

```
public void RunQuery()
{
    try
    {
        var con = new OracleConnection("some connection string");

        con.Open();

        var cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        // ... 

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) when (IsNetworkException(ex))
    {
        // Here, a network exception occurred
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Here, an other exception occurred
    }
}

private static bool IsNetworkException(Exception ex)
{
    var exTmp = ex;
    while (exTmp != null)
    {
        if (exTmp is SocketException)
            return true;

        exTmp = exTmp.InnerException;
    }

    return false;
}
```